# How to lift state two levels up in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Following this [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) by React.

I want to be able to lift states two levels up. Meaning, when an event occurs at the lower level component, I want it to affect the state two levels up. How should I do this? Is this even recommended?

For example, Component A is the parent of Component B, Component B is the parent of Component C. A -> B -> C.

In A,

```
handleChange = (e) => {console.log(e)}
<B onChange={handleChange}/>
```

In B,

```
handleChange = (e) => this.props.onChange(e)
<C onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

In C,

```
handleChange = (e) => this.props.onChange(e)
<button onClick={this.handleChange}></button>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Using your example A->B->C here.
You should create a setter in A.

state of A:

```
this.state={ stateA: "whatever"}
```

function in A:

```
setStateA(newVal){
    this.setState({stateA: newVal});
}
```

Now pass it as property to B

```
<B setStateA={this.setStateA} />
```

In B:

```
<C setStateA={this.props.setStateA} />
```

In C:

```
// some code
this.props.setStateA("a new value");
//some code
```

I think this is the best way to do it. Passing function as property to children. Hope it helps.

Comment: I will consider this method. Thank you.

Comment: Is using 'this' still the optimal way to handle OP's question in 2022?

Comment: Isn't it better to use `useContext` instead to avoid prop drilling?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to recreate the function in the B component, simply passing it along will work.

B will simply look like

```
<C onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
```

Same for C where you can directly attach the event the props to onClick.

Comment: I will consider this method. Thank you.