# Best (functional) way in React to lift state an arbitrary number of levels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458256/how-to-lift-state-two-levels-up-in-react) from 2017 where it was asked how to lift state up two levels in react. The answer used `this` in the context of an OOP design. Five years later, components can be written in functional programming, largely omitting usage of the `this` keyword.

What's the simplest way to lift state up any arbitrary number, n, levels? Is this something best accomplished with tools like redux or is vanilla React sufficient?

For example, I'm unsure how to best pass `deleteItemHandler` (noted in inline comments) from App to Item, passing through Display.

```
function App() {
  const [todoList, todoListSetter] = useState([]);

  const addTodoHandler = (item) => {
    todoListSetter((prevItems) => {
      return [item, ...prevItems]
    });
  };

  const deleteItemHandler = (item) => { //Level 1
    todoListSetter((prevItems) => {
      return prevItems.filter(elem => elem !== item)
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <div >
      <Display removeItem={deleteItemHandler} items={todoList} /> //Level 1->2      
      <Form onSaveItem={addTodoHandler}/>
    </div>
  );
};

const Display = (props) => {
  props.items.map((item) => {
    return(
    <div>
      <Item deleteItemHandler={props.removeItem} value={item}/> //Level 2->3
    </div>)
  });
};

const Form = (props) => {
    
    const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState("");
    const newItemHandler = (event) => {
      setNewItem(event.target.value);
    };   
    
    const submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        props.onSaveItem;

    };
    
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Add item to todo list</h2>
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <label>New Item</label>
                <input type='text' onChange={newItemHandler} />
            </form>
        </div>
    ) 
};

const Item = (props) => {
    
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{props.value}</h1>
            <button onClick={props.deleteItemHandler}>Delete Item</button> //Level 3
        </div>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: State management like Redux or something like [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) should do the job. Which method you choose is highly subjective

Comment: Remember, comments in JSX go in between `{/*` and `*/}`; `//` will render literally as HTML.

Comment: @code, good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example given from the [React documentation for the useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook:

```
const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: "#000000",
    background: "#eeeeee"
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: "#ffffff",
    background: "#222222"
  }
};

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(themes.light);

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={themes.dark}>
      <Toolbar />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemedButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function ThemedButton() {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <button style={{ background: theme.background, color: theme.foreground }}>
      I am styled by theme context!
    </button>
  );
}
```